# Tracking number of recursive calls of Fibonacci number without using global variables in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, recursion, global-variables

```
`
def fib(x):
"""assume x an int >= 0
    Returns Fibnacci of x"""
global numcalls 
numcalls += 1 

if x == 0 or x == 1:
    return 1
else:
    return fib(x-1) + fib(x-2)

def testfib(n):
  for i in range(n+1):
    global numcalls 
    numcalls = 0 
    print 'fib of', i, '=', fib(i)
    print 'fib called', numcalls,'times.'
```

This is the version of using the global variable to track the numbers of recursive calls of Fibonacci,my question is how to write a version without using global variables?

`

Comment: If you make fib a method of a class you could track the call count in an instance variable.

Comment: @jq170727, that's basically the same as using a global variable.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy - Say we have class Fib and there are two instances f1, f2.  Each would have its own encapsulated call count.  I don't think it's basically the same as a global variable because no part of the state would be in any "global" namespace – the only way to access it would be through the f1 / f2 instance references.

Comment: @jq170727, It's still keeping a mutable piece of state outside of the function. You should avoid doing this for all the same reasons we avoid globals.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy A functional style of fib (such as the one in your answer) is generally better then one with side effects for many reasons but I don't agree that global variables and instance variables are "basically the same" (even if they are both to be avoided).

Answer (score 0):

You should change `fib` so that it returns a tuple of `(fib(n), numcalls)`.

```
def fib(x):
    """assume x an int >= 0
        Returns tuple of (Fibonacci of x, number of calls)"""

    if x == 0 or x == 1:
        return 1, 1
    else:
        f1, n1 = fib(x-1)
        f2, n2 = fib(x-2)
        return f1 + f2, n1 + n2 + 1
```